# How to Release Locks on a featureclass in Arcpy

Tags: arcpy

I am new with Arcpy, I have a code for scheme lock on featureclass, Please suggest me how to remove the lock.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import time
import datetime
import pyodbc
import ctypes 
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
import smtplib
import sys


#process: Lock Test on Feature classes
def CheckLock(FeatureClass):
    if arcpy.TestSchemaLock(FeatureClass):
        print "Lock..."
        sys.exit()
#Custom folder for SDE files to give the Python code access to databases - US4491
# DEV VARIABLES

EDIT_SA_DISSOLVE = "Database Connections\DEVESRISQL02_GISDB.sde\GISDB.DBO.CompassArea_1"
CheckLock(EDIT_SA_DISSOLVE)
```

Comment: I think what you should ask is *why* there is a lock on a feature class, rather than how to remove it (which might not even be possible without "hacking"). They exist for a reason. It is not necessarily a problem with a lock on a file, if it originates from your session.

Comment: What kind of lock is it? Why the FC is locked? You have to know the answers to these questions in order to **prevent** FC locking.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to close the database connection at the end of your script using:

```
arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management()
```

see http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/clear-workspace-cache.htm

Comment: try to use del FeatureClass  as you define the variable in your script. It will close your dataset. I have also faced the same problem few weeks ago.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the lock remains

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and found that compacting the geodatabase effectively removed the locks that were persisting.

```
arcpy.management.Compact(<your_gdb>)
```

[ESRI documentation on arcpy.management.Compact()](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/compact.htm)