# ArcGIS Pro Stops working after running a script on ArcGIS Notebook and generates error after a long pause

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-notebook

I was trying to perform Downscaling a Prediction Model Using ArcGIS Notebooks and ArcGIS Pro using the datasets provided by ArcGIS Lab and their instructions from [this mannual](https://www.esri.com/training/catalog/6410bb9f4d750615175acc87/downscaling-a-prediction-model-using-arcgis-notebooks-and-arcgis-pro/). The provided code is:

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import os
import datetime
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    
## Define the file paths for the source data
in_gdb = r"G:\EsriTraining\PredModelDownscale\RegressionData.gdb"
out_gdb = r"G:\EsriTraining\PredModelDownscale\Climate_Downscaling\Climate_Downscaling.gdb"
netcdf_dir = r"G:\EsriTraining\PredModelDownscale\netcdfs"
    
## Define atmospheric variables available for analysis
variables = ["ccb", "cct", "ci", "clivi", "clt", "clwvi", "evspsbl", "hfls", "hfss", "huss", "pr", "prc", "prsn", "prw", "ps", "rlds", "rldscs", "rlus", "rlut", "rlutcs", "rsds", "rsdscs", "rsdt", "rsus", "rsuscs", "sbl", "sfcWind", "tas", "tasmax", "tasmin", "tauu", "tauv", "ts"]
in_fc = "station_data_no_missing"
dist_feature = "Large_Water_Body"
predict_var = "T_MONTHLY"
    
## Create a dictionary to define if a predictor is categorical or not
is_categorical = {"ccb":"false", "cct":"false", "ci":"false", "clivi":"false", "clt":"false", "clwvi":"false", "evspsbl":"false", "hfls":"false", "hfss":"false", "huss":"false", "pr":"false", "prc":"false", "prsn":"false", "prw":"false", "ps":"false", "rlds":"false", "rldscs":"false", "rlus":"false", "rlut":"false", "rlutcs":"false", "rsds":"false", "rsdscs":"false", "rsdt":"false", "rsus":"false", "rsuscs":"false", "sbl":"false", "sfcWind":"false", "tas":"false", "tasmax":"false", "tasmin":"false", "tauu":"false", "tauv":"false", "ts":"false"}

## Utility function for defining input string for Random Forest Regression
def prepare_rf_input(vars, category_dict):
    input_string = []
    [input_string.append(var + ' ' + category_dict[var]) for var in vars]
    return ';'.join(input_string)

#####################################################################
######## Perform Temperature Downscaling at Every Time Slice ########
#####################################################################
## Define Environment Variables for Random Forest Tool
arcpy.env.workspace = in_gdb
arcpy.env.mask = os.path.join(in_gdb, 'US_polygon')
arcpy.env.cellSize = 0.5
    
## Define and select the station data to be subsetted at every time-step
start_time = datetime.datetime(2006,2,1)
selected_stations =  'station_select'
arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(in_fc, selected_stations)

## Define NetCDF files to loop through
netcdfs = [file for file in os.listdir(netcdf_dir) if file.endswith('.nc')]
    
## List to store variable importance
variable_importance = []

## Define the number of prediction rasters
num_rasters = 1
#num_rasters = 60
    
## Create the prediction rasters
for time_slice in range(num_rasters):
    raster_input_list = []
    print('Time Slice = {0}'.format(time_slice))
    
    ## Select Weather Stations that have date at time 
    current_time = start_time + relativedelta(months =+ time_slice)
    arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(selected_stations, 'NEW_SELECTION', "LST_YRMO_Converted = date '{0}'".format(current_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")))
    
    for netcdf in netcdfs:
    
        var_name = netcdf.split('_')[0]
        if var_name in ['prsn', 'sbl']:
            continue
        else:
            #### Create temporary prediction rasters from NetCDFs
            arcpy.md.MakeNetCDFRasterLayer(os.path.join(netcdf_dir, netcdf), var_name, "lon", "lat", var_name + "_raster", None, "time " + str(time_slice + 1), "BY_INDEX", "CENTER")
            raster_input_list.append(var_name + "_raster")
    
    ## String input for input rasters
    raster_input_string = ' #;'.join(raster_input_list)
    raster_input_string += ' #'
    ##String input for matched rasters
    raster_match_string =  [raster_string + ' ' + raster_string for raster_string in raster_input_list]
    raster_match_string = ';'.join(raster_match_string)
    
    ## Perform forest-based regression on selected weather stations and GCM rasters
    arcpy.stats.Forest("PREDICT_RASTER", selected_stations, predict_var, None, None, None, raster_input_string, None, None,  os.path.join(out_gdb, "temp_pred_" + str(time_slice)), None, None, raster_match_string, None, "var_importance", "TRUE", 100, None, None, 100, None, 10, None, None, None, 1)
    
    variable_importance.append(arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray("var_importance", ('*')))
    
print("Analysis is complete.")
```

I prepared the environment according to the training guideline, did not tweaked anything but the  drive. After a long hang, the code generates this error:

```
Time Slice = 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ExecuteError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [7]:
Line 32:    arcpy.stats.Forest("PREDICT_RASTER", selected_stations, predict_var, None, None, None, raster_input_string, None, None,  os.path.join(out_gdb, "temp_pred_" + str(time_slice)), None, None, raster_match_string, None, "var_importance", "TRUE", 100, None, None, 100, None, 10, None, None, None, 1)

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\stats.py, in Forest:
Line 2866:  raise e

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\stats.py, in Forest:
Line 2863:  retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.Forest_stats(*gp_fixargs((prediction_type, in_features, variable_predict, treat_variable_as_categorical, explanatory_variables, distance_features, explanatory_rasters, features_to_predict, output_features, output_raster, explanatory_variable_matching, explanatory_distance_matching, explanatory_rasters_matching, output_trained_features, output_importance_table, use_raster_values, number_of_trees, minimum_leaf_size, maximum_depth, sample_size, random_variables, percentage_for_training, output_classification_table, output_validation_table, compensate_sparse_categories, number_validation_runs, calculate_uncertainty, output_trained_model), True)))

File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py, in <lambda>:
Line 512:   return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))

ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output G:\EsriTraining\PredModelDownscale\Climate_Downscaling\Climate_Downscaling.gdb\temp_pred_0
Failed to execute (Forest).

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What could be the possible solution for that???

Answer (score 0):

Your [error code](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-00201-00225-000210.htm#:%7E:text=000210%3A%20Cannot%20create%20output%20.,-ArcGIS%20Pro%203.1&text=The%20output%20cannot%20be%20created,path%2C%20and%20limited%20access%20rights.) suggests data locking, an incorrect path, or limited access rights.  Confirm the path is valid and that you have read/write permissions to G:\EsriTraining\PredModelDownscale\Climate_Downscaling\Climate_Downscaling.gdb\temp_pred_0

If that is not the problem then figure out where the lock on the geodatabase is happening.  [Maybe start with this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/216420/how-to-release-locks-on-a-featureclass-in-arcpy).